# SwiftUI: How can I move texts or something else with VStack, HStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new in SwiftUI. I would like on the top left in the corner a Button next to the Picker. But when I place the Button, the Picker moves to the right and the Button is to nearly on the edge. How can I place the Button flush over the Headline and the Picker perfectly in the middle from iPhone Nodge?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var Selection = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Picker")
    @State var Detail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.Detail.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("click")
                }.sheet(isPresented: $Detail) {
                    SettingView(showSheetView: self.$Detail, selection: $Selection)
                }
        
        Picker("", selection: $Selection) {
            Text("Selection1").tag(0)
            Text("Selection2").tag(1)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(.horizontal, 89)
            .onReceive(Just(Selection)) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set($0, forKey: "Picker")
            }
            }
            PageOne()
        }
    }
}

struct PageOne: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("some Text")
            }.navigationTitle("Headline")
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
   
    @Binding var showSheetView: Bool
    @Binding var selection: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                Text("Test")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Select something"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.showSheetView = false
                }) {
                    Text("Ok")
                        .bold()
                        
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `ZStack` to show your `Button` and `Picker` without pushing them.

something like this:

```
var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.Detail.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("click")
                        }.sheet(isPresented: $Detail) {
                            SettingView(showSheetView: self.$Detail, selection: $Selection)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Picker("", selection: $Selection) {
                            Text("Selection1").tag(0)
                            Text("Selection2").tag(1)
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()).padding(.horizontal, 89)
                            .onReceive(Just(Selection)) {
                                UserDefaults.standard.set($0, forKey: "Picker")
                            }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                PageOne()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah Okay thanks. Yes the Picker is on the right place but the button is still on the edge. How can I place the Button exactly over the Headline, so that the button is exactly above the "H" from "Headline"?

Comment: You can add some padding to the first Stack

HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.Detail.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Text("click")
                            }.sheet(isPresented: $Detail) {
                                SettingView(showSheetView: self.$Detail, selection: $Selection)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                       .padding(20)

Comment: Okay cool. But now is the distance between Picker and Nodge bigger as previously. How can I fix this?

Comment: @lula08 try adding just horizontal padding to your button. like: `.padding(.horizontal, 20)`